# Why does a sound wave on encountering a low pressure region gets reflected with a "phase change of π"?

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions

I am particularly concerned with the reason for phase change of π. This is observed in organ pipes at their open ends. The waves on encountering the open atmosphere(low pressure region) reflects back along with a phase change of π. Currently i am unable to work out any reason for such behavior of the pressure waves.

Comment: what have you considered so far? have you searched with google? you need to show your prior work. note that your phase change is the same as multiplying by -1 .

Comment: Yeah, i searched about it and what i got was the fact that phase change occurs at open end(as in an organ pipe) but no explanation to this phenomena

Comment: Hello and welcome to [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)! Can you further describe the context of your question? For example, if there is a wave function that you are using, the hypotheses that you are assuming, and the computations you already tried. You can also add some tags as "Acoustics".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with transmission line theory

see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_of_signals_on_conducting_lines

Although this is electrical it is analogous to acoustic.

**Answer to your question via an electrical analog example:**

As the wave travels down the medium its voltage and current components are determined by the impedance of the medium.  If at the boundary of the medium the impedance suddenly goes to zero, say, then the voltage component must go to zero there.  The only way this can happen is if a reflected wave is created with a voltage equal and opposite to the voltage of the impinging (incoming) wave--i.e. phase shifted by 180 degrees (or by pi radians). Then the summation of the waves at the boundary is zero.